# Http.Get() always returning undefined in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-http, angular2-observables

Following a tutorial where the instructor is building a spotify music search with the spotify api. Followed every single step the instructor did but the problem is my data never comes back, I get undefined and nothing shows up on screen. However if i hit the api directly in my browser the json data is displayed but never displays in my app.

Actually I've seen a lot of questions like this but none of them solved my problem. I thought it might be a network related issue but when i set a breakpoint I could see the result in the response but nothing ever gets loaded into view, undefined is being loaded into the console

```
**search.component.html**
<h1>Need Music?</h1>
<p class="lead">
  Use the ngSpotify app to browse new releases of your favorite songs. See what your favorite artistes are up to.
</p>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="searchStr" [(ngModel)]="searchStr" (keyup.enter)="searchMusic()" class="form-control" placeholder="Search music here..."/>
  </div>
</form>

**search.component.ts**
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SpotifyService } from '../../Services/spotify.service';  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _spotifyservice: SpotifyService) { }

  searchStr: string;
  searchResult;

  searchMusic() {
    return this._spotifyservice.searchMusic(this.searchStr)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.searchResult = data;
       },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }    

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

**spotify.service.ts**
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'


@Injectable()
export class SpotifyService {
  private searchUrl: string;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  searchMusic(str: string, type = 'artist') {
    this.searchUrl = `http://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=${str}&offset=0&limit=20&type=${type}&market=US`

    return this._http.get(this.searchUrl)
      .map((res) => { res.json() })
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }

  handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error || 'server error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are mapping like so:

```
.map((res) => { res.json() })
```

you need to use `return`

```
.map((res) => { return res.json() })
```

or use just:

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Wqk4qzD81bX11loLStD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your [(ngModel)] will not work in this case so you need to use ElementRef to refer the input text box

```
<input type="text" name="searchStr" #input (keyup.enter)="searchMusic(input.value)" class="form-control" placeholder="Search music here..."/>
```

Modify your method as

```
searchMusic(searchStr:string) {
    return this._spotifyservice.searchMusic(searchStr)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.searchResult = data;
       },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
```

In your component declare an element ref as

```
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;
```